# PostgreSQL error: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "pgadmin"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am making a Telegram bot with a PostgreSQL database. Everything works correctly on the local computer, but when I upload the code to the server using docker-compose, the following errors appear in the console from time to time:

```
2021-10-10 02:08:58.865 UTC [3458] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgadmin"
2021-10-10 02:08:58.865 UTC [3458] DETAIL:  Role "pgadmin" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 94: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"

2021-10-09 16:27:22.198 UTC [2259] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgsql"
2021-10-09 16:27:22.198 UTC [2259] DETAIL:  Role "pgsql" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 94: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"

2021-10-09 16:25:16.113 UTC [2250] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-10-09 16:25:18.992 UTC [2252] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 94: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"

2021-10-09 21:06:32.169 UTC [2831] FATAL:  expected password response, got message type 0
2021-10-09 21:07:39.610 UTC [2834] FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 0.0: server supports 2.0 to 3.0
2021-10-09 21:07:39.819 UTC [2835] FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 255.255: server supports 2.0 to 3.0
2021-10-09 21:07:40.029 UTC [2836] FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
```

And I don't use these users. It seems to me that someone else is trying to access the database. If so, is it possible to somehow specify the IP addresses from which traffic will be allowed? But my bot parses sites, so you need to limit the IP so that it would not affect its work. Thanks!

**UPD:**
As I was prompted in the comments, maybe the contents of the docker files will help
Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.5

WORKDIR /src
COPY requirements.txt /src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /src
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  steamtrader_db:
    container_name: steamtrader_db
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:10-2
    environment:
      PG_PASSWORD: $PGPASSWORD
      DB_USER: $PGUSER
      DB_PASS: $PGPASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DATABASE
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - steamtrader_botnet
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql

  steamtrader_bot:
    container_name: steamtrader
    build:
      context: .
    command: python bot.py
    restart: always
    networks:
      - steamtrader_botnet
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    depends_on:
      - steamtrader_db


networks:
  steamtrader_botnet:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Hmmmz: What would be the meaning of this line in the logging: (`Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 94: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"`). did you do some research on that line? If might give you the answer to your question....

Comment: Configure [listen_addresses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html) properly, there is probably no need to expose postgresql. That way you won't even get a log entry because the connection attempt fails at tcp level. If your app accessing postgresql lives in the same docker container, `listen_addresses = localhost` will do the job.

Comment: @Steeeve do I need to specify exactly localhost or ip address of my local PC? When I specified `listen_addresses = 'localhost, * my_ip *'`, after `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`, everything I wrote was deleted in the file and `listen_addresses` is equal to `'*'` again

Comment: I can't help you with that in docker, it would be guessing instead of knowledge... Try adding the docker tag to your question and include your dockerfile to attract the attention of some docker pros.

Comment: You need to configure your database connection (bot) according to the setup you provided to the actual database. The content of environment variables are credentials you are looking for. Additionally, as mentioned your database probably don't need to be exposed to internet so you can close the port mapping in the database configuration.

Comment: @ItsIIIyTh1K could you find out the reason?